# how do i use a ado.net dataservice to check if a row exists?

Tags: ado.net, dataservice

```
var svc = new LocationDataServiceContext();
var q = from c in svc.LocationTable
                      where c.ID == int.Parse(location.ID)
                      select c;
if (q.ToArray().Length == 0)
```

id there a neater way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

yes, I believe so...

```
    var svc = new LocationDataServiceContext();

    if (svc.LocationTable.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ID == int.Parse(location.ID) != null))
    {

    }
```

I thought there was an Exist() method... but I guess not.

Comment: The Exist() method is part of IList<T> or one of its bases... But you would want to convert it to a List cause then you'd be pulling all the records...